# Is there any data returned from the Forge Data Management Search api to indicate a model is deleted?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When using GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/search, Forge Data Management API on a model with a deleted last version, is there a any information in the "attributes" or other returned data that indicates the file is deleted?

Currently, a second call to GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions is used to determine if the latest version is deleted (below) but it would be preferable to not call another request to get this information.

Returned JSON from /versions (with some data removed):

```
    "data": [{
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.w0cwXPUwQziKIHtKBtYRaA?version=3",
        "attributes": {
            "versionNumber": 3,
            "extension": {
                "type": "versions:autodesk.core:Deleted",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.core:Deleted-1.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "originalName": "**.rvt"
                }
            }
        }]
```

Comment: Hi @Mandi, I might not well understand your question, are you looking for an option to search out all deleted files by, or you cannot find any attribute that indicates if a file is deleted from the response payload of folder Search?  In addition, I tested with A360, after deleting a file, :item_id/versions will return 404. I'd appreciate if you could elaborate a bit more on the context you are testing: delete a file in A360 folder, and call :item_id/versions with the same version id?

Comment: I'm trying to eliminate the files that are deleted from the results.  I discovered the filter filter[hidden]=false from the Document management help.  I assume the hidden = false attribute will give me the information I am seeking?

Answer (score 0):

The json attribute.hidden = true seems to indicate deleted.  This can be accessed via the filter[hidden] = true.  I'm closing this as the correct answer.

Comment: glad to know it is solved by yourself. It sounds you are working with BIM 360 Docs data, instead of Autodesk 360, in which I do not see hidden can work with Autodesk 360 items. The API help also indicates hidden filter works with BIM 360 .https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/#hidden-items-and-folders .anyway, if there is any further questions, please let us know.